# CSS issues related to nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Regarding the issue of nuxt3, the css I introduced in nuxt.config.ts, after packaging, the css in this file is all internal styles. Is there any way to put it in a link?

[image]

I want to put the globally imported css into a file, and then import it, I don't know if it is supported